# ScalaFx Group wrapped nodes data extraction

Tags: scalafx

Trying to extract Group wrapped node data seems really tricky. Any pointers getting data inside node objects (which by definition have no children) like in code below I would like to get Rectangle.userData inside Group(VBox(Rectangle))?

```
def west(): Unit = {
  def boxPart(ix: Int): VBox = new VBox {
    padding = Insets(2, 5, 8, 5)
    userData = "My userData VBox wrap"
    children = (
      new Rectangle {
        width = 250 
        height = 125 
        fill = Color.DeepSkyBlue
        userData = "My userData Rectangle wrap"+ix.toString
      }
    )
  } 

  val packet = new Group(boxPart(12345))

  val vboxproof = packet.children.get(0).userData

  println("TESTER:" + vboxproof)

  // getting rectangle userData ???
}

west
```

Answer (score 1):

Children of `Group` are generic `Node`s. You need to access actual type of a child to access additional properties. Also keep in mind that you are navigating the JavaFX scene graph, so need to "cast" children to JavaFX types. You can create `vboxproof` using something like this to get children of `VBox`:

```scala
  val vboxproof = packet.children.get(0) match {
    case v : javafx.scene.layout.VBox => v.children.get(0).userData
    case v => "Unexpected type: " + v.getClass.getName
  }
```